# Could not load file or assembly tools\EntityFramework .PowerShell.Utility.dll'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

When try to Install Entity Framework 6.1.3 From Package Manager console.
I get following output.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework 
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with respect to project 'OnlineShop', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder 'D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder 'D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1'
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or asse
mbly 'file:///D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop
\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' o
r one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\E
ntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $Too
lsP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\E
ntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load fi
le or assembly 'file:///D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\
OnlineShop\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll'
 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\E
ntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or asse
mbly 'file:///D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop
\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' o
r one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\E
ntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $Too
lsP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\E
ntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load fi
le or assembly 'file:///D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\
OnlineShop\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll'
 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\OnlineShop\packages\E
ntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException


Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to OnlineShop
```

As you can see,there is exception.But after all,Entity Framework 6.1.3 is succesfully added to the project,in spite of exceptions.Besides when i add reference to System.Data.Entity,and try to use it in code.I can't connect to the System.Data.Entity namespace and use libraries of this namespace.Is it connected somehow to mentioned above exception,and how to fix this?

Comment: try to open Visual Studio in Administrator mode and try again

Answer (score 79):

Use the command:

```
EntityFramework6\Add-Migration
```

Microsoft has changed name of `cmdmidlet`

Comment: This may be the best answer, since downgrading EF to older version using VS 2022 cause an ArgumentNullException when generating/executing migration

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by downgrading Entity Framework 6.1.3 to Entity Framework 6.1.2.Probably it is bug of last version.

Comment: This worked for me with EntityFramework V6.4.0, down to V6.2.0

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same issue with EntityFramework 6.4.0 in visual studio 2019 (v16.5.4) in a .NET Framework 4.5 Project.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\InfrastructureManager\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\InfrastructureManager\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-P ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\InfrastructureManager\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\InfrastructureManager\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\InfrastructureManager\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

Solution was (Package Manager Console):

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.2
Enable-Migrations
```

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall **EntityFramework** from your project then **restart** your project and **reinstall** EntityFramework

Comment: To whom may help: **Restarting VS2022** (same issue with EF6.4.4 vs EF6.2.0) **did the trick**. **Without it I kept getting the same error**, even though there was no ".....packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0" folder anywhere. 
Thanx Davood and @Christian

Answer (score 5):

For me this was fixed by upgrading all EF projects in the solution to the same EF version. I do not agree that MS products suck. I love the VS Ide environment. Nothing compares to it.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had changed some of my projects from 6.2 to 6.4.4.  But then when i changed all projects over, it deleted the 6.2 folder and stopped getting confused.  It did require an extra clean/rebuild solution and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: updating all projects to ef 6.4.4 fixes the issue for me, thks.

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio after removing older EF version, otherwise, it did not work

Comment: For me the trick was to upgrade ALL PROJECTS in my solution to 6.4.4 then restart Visual Studio –

Answer (score 2):

I was using EF version 6.4.4. Changing to 6.2.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if you don't have the right "Default project" selected in the Package Manager Console.  Switch this to your main application project and it will work.

Alternatively you can use the `-ProjectName` option like this:

`Add-Migration -Name "Some changes" -ProjectName MyWebProject`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error and solved by extracting all of the tools folder in the EntityFramework.6.1.3.nupkg.  You can find this package in this folder:

```
[your solution directory]\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @maksym-trubaiev i realized that you can simply delete the old EF Folder, then there won't be any mixups anymore

```sh
$ rm -r packages/EntityFramework.6.1.3/
```

(where in my case, `6.1.3` is the old version, as i upgrade to `6.4.4`)

Answer (score 0):

In my case change Dll from EF 6.4.4 to EF 6.0.0 fix it

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I created a .NetStand (2.1) project that referenced a NuGet package that has an EF (6.1) dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.2
Enable-Migrations

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading all the projects to latest EntityFramework (6.4.4)