# Entity Framework gives error "Could not load file or assembly", "FileNotFoundException" every time whenever I reopen visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2019, entity-framework-6.4

I am using visual studio 2019 Ent and EntityFramework.6.4.4.
Whenever I'm restarting my VS19 and going to access EF it gives me the following error with code first approach.

```
 Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///("Project Name")\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. The 
system cannot find the file specified."
At "(Project Name)"\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:782 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-P ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At "(Project Name)"\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:783 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///"(Project Name)"\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system 
cannot find the file specified."
At "(Project Name)"\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:811 char:5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

What I have tried so far:
I found one temporary solution that by reinstalling every time nugete package i.e entity framework and it works.
But this is annoying and definitely not the solution. Looking for a permanent solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a version mismatch. You wrote about EF 6.4.4, but, as your error message states, EF 6.2.0 can not be found. Please check app.config, packages.config and csproj-files. Also check your \packages folder for EF packages, that are not used (anymore) and remove them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my main issue is the same, I need to uninstall EF after every restart and then install, Version is changing automatically to EF 6.2.0.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was executing the

> Add-Migration

command. Instead, I used

> EntityFramework6\Add-Migration

And I had no more errors. (Thanks to this answer I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951090/2546759)

Another thing which did the trick was:

1. Make sure that all projects in the solution are using same EF version.
2. Restart Visual Studio.

(As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70004476/2546759)